# Filters along with multi_match query in Elasticsearch v2.3.5

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and Nest so please pardon my ignorance. I would like to use filters along with multi_match query in Elasticsearch v2.3.5 but so far I am not able to figure it out. I think once I got it working for Elasticsearch I should be able to map it to Nest.

Below is my JSON data structure:

```
{
   "contentID":1,
   "categoryID":0,
   "title":"...",
   "description":"...",
   "contentHtml":"...",
   "version":2,
   "parentContentID":0,
   "displayOrder":0,
   "freshdeskID":0,
   "isDraft":false,
   "isCommentingEnabled":false,
   "isArticle":false,
   "grandParentContentID":0,
   "isAnyParentDraft":false
}
```

and below is my working search query (without any filters):

```
POST contents/supportitem/_search?pretty=true
{
  "size": 150,
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "contentHtml": {
        "fragment_size": 245
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "title",
      "contentID",
      "description",
      "thumbnailUrl",
      "isDraft",
      "isAnyParentDraft",
      "grandParentContentID"
    ]
  },"query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "query": "query typed by user",
      "tie_breaker": 0.3,
      "fields": [
        "title^1.1",
        "additionalContents^1.2",
        "contentHtml^1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to show only those records in search result to user where:

```
grandParentContentID != 0 and
isDraft != false and
isAnyParentDraft != false
```

I have tried may different queries but I am not able to figure out how to write this.

Couple of NOT working queries, include:

```
POST contents/supportitem/_search?pretty=true
{
  "size": 150,
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "contentHtml": {
        "fragment_size": 245
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "title",
      "contentID",
      "description",
      "thumbnailUrl",
      "isDraft",
      "isAnyParentDraft",
      "grandParentContentID"
    ]
  },"query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "query": "Tile map server resources",
      "tie_breaker": 0.3,
      "fields": [
        "title^1.1",
        "additionalContents^1.2",
        "contentHtml^1"
      ]
    },"filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "term": {
            "isAnyParentDraft": "false"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST contents/supportitem/_search?pretty=true
{
  "size": 150,
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "contentHtml": {
        "fragment_size": 245
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "title",
      "contentID",
      "description",
      "thumbnailUrl",
      "isDraft",
      "isAnyParentDraft",
      "grandParentContentID"
    ]
  },"query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "query": "Tile map server resources",
      "tie_breaker": 0.3,
      "fields": [
        "title^1.1",
        "additionalContents^1.2",
        "contentHtml^1"
      ]
    },"filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "field": {"isAnyParentDraft": "false"}
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get `"failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"`

I got this working but I am not able figure out how to add more filters:

```
POST contents/supportitem/_search?pretty=true
{
  "size": 150,
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "contentHtml": {
        "fragment_size": 245
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "title",
      "contentID",
      "description",
      "thumbnailUrl",
      "isDraft",
      "isAnyParentDraft",
      "grandParentContentID"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "type": "cross_fields",
          "query": "deleted",
          "tie_breaker": 0.3,
          "fields": [
            "title^1.1",
            "additionalContents^1.2",
            "contentHtml^1"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "isAnyParentDraft": "false"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have referred below questions:

[ElasticSearch with multi_match AND bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835679/elasticsearch-with-multi-match-and-bool) - Has only one filter

[Elasticsearch: multi_match no effect with filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304505/elasticsearch-multi-match-no-effect-with-filters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good start, you're almost there:

```
POST contents/supportitem/_search?pretty=true
{
  "size": 150,
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "contentHtml": {
        "fragment_size": 245
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "title",
      "contentID",
      "description",
      "thumbnailUrl",
      "isDraft",
      "isAnyParentDraft",
      "grandParentContentID"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "type": "cross_fields",
          "query": "deleted",
          "tie_breaker": 0.3,
          "fields": [
            "title^1.1",
            "additionalContents^1.2",
            "contentHtml^1"
          ]
        }
      },
      "must_not": [
         {
           "term": {
             "isAnyParentDraft": "false"
           }
         },
         {
           "term": {
             "isDraft": "false"
           }
         },
         {
           "term": {
             "grandParentContentID": 0
           }
         }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```